# R write.csv file can't be imported in Excel (weird characters appear)

Tags: r, excel, csv, encoding

I have a problem with a file that I have generated in R using "write.csv".

When I try to import it in Excel, I have some "weird characters". And finally I can't open it.

Here my code for the write.csv:

```
write.csv(all_sdoub,file="all_new.csv",fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

I have tried with fileEncoding ASCII, or without file encoding, I always have the same problem. I tried to send the file to a colleague, she has the same problem.

I work on a R session on a linux server. Any idea of what is happening?

edit: I have tried to had this line:

```
options(encoding = "UTF-8")
```

But it doesn't change anything to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As it is noted at a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel) you need to import CSV file to Excel.

You can do this under **Data tab** using the "**From text**" button where you are able specify the encoding, delimiters and so on.

Comment: The problem happens when I import the file in Excel. I see the weird characters in the "preview".

Comment: @Oolis can you check the file in Notepad++ so see which encoding is being actually used.

Comment: I don't know what encoding it is. Here a sample of what I can see in Notepad++:RDX2
X
                 to_save     c     jÔ      2G      2G      2G      2G      2G      2G      2G      2G      2G      2G      2G      2G      2G

Comment: And after: §S.@FzáG®@Gù´è<.@Ft2í×á@Gõ¹u0àq@EÆ“é>š@E¡™™™™š@FyPÈ?Ãf@Fjó|
©@E™‡eC@EÐ£×
=q@G¾F„³@H%0ì¨|@HFŠ¶¤@HE'Ò}4  (there's also some sorts of squares, but I can't display them on Stackoverflow)

Comment: @Oolis check the **encoding tab** in notepad++ to see the file encoding. Are symbols displayed correctly in notepad++?

Comment: Hello, no, I have the same problem in Notepad++. I have tried all the encoding, I always have the weird characters.

Comment: Hm, I it hard to help without the [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: for information things are better now that Ftcix has been added to the server!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it through changing the file name I was using to store the csv.